# Force field "location" in layout_builder

Tags: 8

I'm using layout_builder and have a node bundle that allows for layout customization per entity.

Right now, I have a default layout that places a few fields on the page. The problem is, users can then move these fields to the top or middle of the page, or remove these fields entirely, and I actually want to FORCE some fields on the page. So for example, if my node has a disclosure that I *always want at the bottom of the page* and really, I don't want someone removing it at all...  any suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: It's not a perfect solution to your problem - but you might be able to figure out a work around by limiting the layout builder permissions for your front end users using this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/layout_builder_perms

Comment: If you have a disclosure you _always_ want a the bottom of the page, make it a block or something else instead of being part of the node.

Comment: _"make it a block or something else instead of being part of the node."_

But it's a disclosure _for the node_. It's a field on the node.